# Дата прописью в java

Tags: java, дата

Как вывести дату словами в Java?

Пример:

11 09 2018 — одиннадцатое сентября две тысячи восемнадцатый год

Comment: Что имеется в виду под `пропись`? `Date` to `String` надо сделать?

Comment: вывод даты прописью @ЮрийСП6

Comment: Всё ещё не ясно что за `прописью `. В `Java` нет такого понятия. Покажите в вопросе пример того что должно получиться

Comment: Если имеется в виду то, что у вас в предыдущем вопросе - то точно также надо делать. Взять числа и преобразовать в строки. Конкретно для дат такое отдельно где-то в виде библиотеки вряд ли существует.

Comment: согласен @Maxgmer

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev что такое пропись?))

Comment: вот пример для тех кто не понимает что такое пропись 
11 09 2018 
одиннадцатое сентября две тысячи восемнадцатый год
@Maxgmer

Comment: @AkbarIlxambaev это называется строка, String.

Comment: `Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String s = formatter.format(date);` Здесь yyyy - это год, MM - месяц и тп. Настраивайте, как надо.

Comment: Я хорошо понимаю вас он должен выводить дату буквами как я написал в комментариях @Maxgmer

Answer (score 2):

По хорошему надо конечно же писать класс потомок [DateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) в которой надо реализовывать перевод из чисел в пропись. Задача прямо скажем непростая...

Однако не все так плохо, для quick-fix можно использовать либу [tradukisto](https://github.com/allegro/tradukisto), которая умеет в мультиязычном варианте переводить более-менее любое число `Integer` в пропись. Грубо говоря надо разложить дату на 3 числа: дату, месяц и год и каждый из них прогнать через соответствующий метод, типа:

```
int day=22;
int month=11;
int year=2019;
ValueConverters converter = ValueConverters.RUSSIAN_INTEGER;
String dayAsWords = converter.asWords(new Integer(day));
String monthAsWords = converter.asWords(new Integer(month));
String yearAsWords = converter.asWords(new Integer(year));

System.out.println(dayAsWords+" "+monthAsWords+" "+yearAsWords);
```

Answer (score 0):

Такого паттерна в Java нет, придется самому числа словами заменять к сожалению. Например разбить дату на составляющие

день месяц год, и составлять из них строку